# javascript insertBefore upon addEventListener only once

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have an `input type="number"` field where I want to control that no negative numbers are inserted. Doing this with `addEventListener` but that executes upon every digit you enter into that field.

```js
var number = document.querySelector("input[type=number]")

number.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var valeur = number.value
  if (valeur.startsWith("-")) {
    erreur = document.createElement("div")
    erreur.innerHTML = "No negative numbers."
    number.appendChild(erreur)
    number.parentNode.insertBefore(erreur, number.nextSibling);
  } else {
    erreur.remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" step="any" name="amount">
```

What should I change so the message shows up only once?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the creation of the div outside of the if condition

```
let erreur = document.createElement("div")
number.addEventListener('input', function() {
```

```js
var number = document.querySelector("input[type=number]")
let erreur = document.createElement("div")

number.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var valeur = number.value
  if (valeur.startsWith("-")) {
    erreur.innerHTML = "No negative numbers."
    number.appendChild(erreur)
    number.parentNode.insertBefore(erreur, number.nextSibling);
  } else {
    erreur.remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" step="any" name="amount">
```